# How to avoid memory leaks with the use of Node Streams and promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, memory-leaks, node-streams

I try to wrap node streams in an async function. But I'm wondering if the following code leaks memory. Will `readStream` and `result` be garbage collected after the promise is resolved(rejected)? If not, how should I avoid the memory leak?

```js
async function readFile(path, keyword) {
  const readStream = fs.createReadStream(path, {encoding: 'utf8'});
  let result = await getCachedResult(); // getCachedResult is another async function
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    readStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
      if (chunk.includes(keyword)) {
         result += chunk;
      }
    })
    readStream.on('error', (err) => {
        reject(err)
        readStream.close()
    })
    readStream.on('end', () => {
        resolve(result)
        readStream.close()
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: FYI, this code `if (chunk.includes(keyword))` is problematic because chunk boundaries can be anywhere in the data including right across the middle of a keyword.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks. The code snippet is a simplified version of my code. In reality, I use Readline module to read one line at a time.

Comment: Please don't simplify in this fundamental a way.    Please post your REAL code on all future questions.  For some unknown reason, people think they should post pseudo code here or reduced/simplified code and that often prevents us from either understanding the real problem or suggesting the best solution.  You're asking about garbage collection and then not showing your REAL code.  Nobody can actually  answer for your real code because you didn't show it and, in fact, you had other modules involved that could have affected the garbage collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currernt JavaScript memory garbage collection algorithms are based on removing data objects and values (including environment record objects containing function variables and parameters) that *can't be reached in code*.

So what data objects and values inside the `async function readFile` body are reachable **after** it returns a Promise object?

No references to `path` or `keyword` are retained after returning, so they are eligible for GC.

References to `readStream`, `result`, `resolve`, `reject` `chunk`, and `err` are only held by the anonymous functions handling stream events registered on the stream.

The handler functions are reachable from the `readStream` instance object ( or its event emitters).

The `readStream` object is responsible for removing references to callbacks that can no longer be made: either after the `end` event itself, or after calling `readStrem.close`. Either way you don't need to be concerned about creating memory leaks by using promises or read streams.

Comment: Perfect explanation: the objects are not garbage-collected when the promise is settled, but when the stream is closed and garbage-collected.